# Economy leaderboard command: undefined

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

I am making a discord economy/currency bot, and this is the leaderboard command. It works, but whenever I run the command !leaderboard, I don't get any of the user's tags, I just get the undefined#0000. I would like my leaderboard command to show the users with the highest amount of currency.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
        name: "leaderboard",
        description: 'server\'s $ leaderboard',
        aliases: ['lb'],
    }
    module.exports.run = async (message) => {
        let money = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`money_`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
        if (!money.length) {
            let noEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor("BLUE")
                .setFooter("No leaderboard")
            return message.channel.send(noEmbed)
        };

        money.length = 10;
        var finalLb = "";
        for (var i in money) {
            let currency1;
            let fetched = await db.fetch(`currency_${message.guild.id}`);
            if (fetched == null) {
                currency1 = ''
            } else {
                currency1 = fetched
            }
            if (money[i].data === null) money[i].data = 0
            finalLb += `**${money.indexOf(money[i]) + 1}. ${message.guild.members.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? message.guild.members.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[1]).tag : "undefined#0000"}** - ${money[i].data} ${currency1}\n`;
        };

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(message.guild.name)
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setDescription(finalLb)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Command: !help for currency commands')
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
let money = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`money_${message.guild.id}`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
money.length = 10;

var finalLb = "";
for (var i in money) {
  finalLb += `**${money.indexOf(money[i])+1}. ${client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[1]) ? client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[1]).tag : "Unknown User#0000"}** - ${money[i].data}\n`;
}
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(`Global Coin Leaderboard!`, message.guild.iconURL())
.setColor("#7289da")
.setDescription(finalLb)
.setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setTimestamp()
message.channel.send(embed);
```

I personally use above code for my bot and it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the `client.login('token')` at the bottom of your code. Maybe the bot can't find the user tag's because of that?

Comment: Isn't it assumed that the client is already logged in at this point? Otherwise how would the client emit a message event and call a command file

Comment: @Elitezen Well, they could be using a command handler, like I do with my bots, so the client.login can be in the main.js file, which would explain the bot booting up correctly.